# Grant type selection for OAuth2 implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I would like to build a web based application using Spring Boot micro service. I am planning to use OAuth2 and OpenID Connect to implement authentication and authorization in my application. What grant type I have to choose to implement OAuth2 if my application is going to be single page application (Angular.js for front end Spring Boot services for backend)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Implicit](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/) or [Authorization Code](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) flow with a single page app :

> In order for a single-page app to use the Authorization Code flow, it must be able to make a POST request to the authorization server. This means if the authorization server is on a different domain, the server will need to support the appropriate CORS headers. If supporting CORS headers is not an option, then the service may use the Implicit Flow instead.
>   [oauth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/)

but it's recommanded to use Authorization Code flow :

> It is generally not recommended to use the implicit flow (and some servers prohibit this flow entirely). In the time since the spec was originally written, the industry best practice has changed to recommend that public clients should use the authorization code flow with the PKCE extension instead. [oauth.com](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/)

Comment: *but it's recommanded to use Authorization Code flow* No, not in general, only in combination **with PKCE**.